# How to remove null value in array for BigQuery?

Tags: arrays, split, google-bigquery

I have a query about BigQuery,
Please see the example below:

```
SELECT SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(0)] part1,
   SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(1)] part2,
   SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(2)] part3,
   SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(3)] part4,
   ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(path, '/')),
   SPLIT(path, '/') 
FROM (SELECT "/a/b/" path)
```

As seen below, the result is like this.
The question is, how can I remove the part1 and part 4 data,
and make the f0_ a 2 but not 4?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) arr_length, arr
FROM (
  SELECT 
     ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(path, '/')) part WHERE part != '') arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

You can test above with sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "/a/b/" path
)
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) arr_length, arr
FROM (
  SELECT 
     ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(path, '/')) part WHERE part != '') arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

with result

```
Row arr_length  arr  
1   2           a    
                b
```

this is the closets I see to what you expect

Comment: Hi thanks, in this case, how can I replace SELECT "/a/b/" path into a SELECT FROM query? Thanks

Comment: just remove WITH section - it is here just for you to test - see update in my answer

Comment: SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) arr_length, arr
FROM (
  SELECT 
     ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(SELECT page_urlpath FROM `test`, '/')) part WHERE part != '') arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)

the page_urlpath is something like "\customer\path\"... thanks